# Modify the META "Robots"

Tags: joomla-3.x, metadata

I want to modify the Robots Meta Tag like

```
<meta name="robots" content="nosnippet" />
```

But Joomla give me only the choice between (NO)Index and (No)Follow and his combination in a article.

What is the best solution to modify this field with [other robots meta tags](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_meta_tag)?

Comment: `setMetaData()` looks useful.  You might get some clues from https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/10190/12352  Have you tried any techniques yet? Are you using any templates?

Comment: @mickmackusa I use the beeze template.

Comment: Have you had a good sniff around the JED for solutions and/or inspiration? Perhaps there is something like https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/meta-robots/ that could prove helpful.

Comment: @mickmackusa I don't want install a additional plug-in Scott performance. I will try to modify the beeze template. If success I will post the solution.